# Error Vue.js "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Did everything on [gorails](https://gorails.com/episodes/using-vuejs-for-nested-forms-part-1?autoplay=1) tutorial, but something wrong.
error message in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined   
    at normalizeProps (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1291)   
    at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1363)   
    at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1372)   
    at Vue$3.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:4268)   
    at new Vue$3 (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:4384)  
    at HTMLDocument.eval (hello_vue.js?94ab:29)     
    at Object.t.dispatch (turbolinks.self-)   
    at r.t.Controller.r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad ...)   
    at r.t.Controller.r.pageLoaded (t...)   
    at turbolinks.self...
```

Hello_vue file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import TurbolinksAdapter from "vue-turbolinks"
import VueResource from "vue-resource"

Vue.use(VueResource);

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

    Vue.http.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content");

  var element = document.getElementById("team-form")

  if(element != null){

    var team = JSON.parse(element.dataset.team);
    var players_attributes = JSON.parse(element.dataset.playersAttributes);
    players_attributes.forEach(function(player){
        player._destroy = null  
    })
    team.players_attributes = players_attributes;

    var app = new Vue({
        el: element,
        mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter],
        data: function(){
            return { team: team }
        },
        methods: {
            addPlayer: function(){
                team.players_attributes.push({
                id: null,
                name: "",
                _destroy: null
                })
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

as I understand, an error in the initialization of the App object, but I can not understand in what exactly. I kind of did it right.

Comment: I am getting this as well, it is happening when I use object3D as a mixin from vue-threejs. When I walk through it. It fails because the mixin is a function and doesn't have any options property. I think this is probably a bug in the vue framework.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

error in
mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter]

removed that line and added
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter);
after
Vue.use(VueResource);
and it all worked

Comment: Is this change documented anywhere? I'm having some other issues and I'm wondering if my settings are just out-of-date.

Answer (score 4):

I've got this issue by misspelling a variable in the Vue mixins array.
for example:

```
import file from '../folder/with/file'
export default: {
    mixins: [
        fil
    ]
}
```

should be

```
import file from '../folder/with/file'
export default: {
    mixins: [
        file
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to the party *and since this was the second answer google showed*, thought this would help someone!

If anyone faced this because of provide/inject, I might probably have to do with vue2 / vue3. I read articles on provide/inject in vue3 and used it in my vue2 project ‍♂️

I was using `reactive` in vue2 like:

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'

provide() {
  return {
    loadingState: new reactive(() => this.loadingState)
  }
}
```

Later changed it to:

```
provide() {
  return {
    loadingState: this.loadingState
  }
}
```